# Angular2 input not triggering change event

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I have an input that is being updated from from a query, however, the (change) event is not triggered when the input field is updated.

Html for input:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="inputValue" id="itemText" (ngModelChange)="setNewItem($event)">
```

Function in component file for input:

```
setNewItem(item){
console.log("Triggered");
return this.ds.setItem(item);  }
```

I'm updating the input field in my index html like so:

```
 <script>
 ....
 onSelect: function (request, response) {
        var urlApi = 'http://localhost:8088/Badges/Details/' + request.item;
                   $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlApi,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                      document.getElementById("itemText").value = response.items[0].item; } 
     }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: use [(ngMode)l]="inputValue" instead of [ngModel]="inputValue"

Comment: I don't find any problem with ur code. It should work. Check the console for errors, which might be unrelated to this.

Comment: That does not trigger the event either, however, you are right I should be using 2 way bindings, thanks

Comment: @Muthukumar the console does not show any errors either sadly, however when I type directly into the input field the event is triggered

Comment: @TestNInja "however when I type directly into the input field the event is triggered" - I thought you were complaining that the event was not firing. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Muthukumar I would like the event to fire when the input is updated from the query, not when I directly type into it

Comment: @TestNInja I think what you are doing is against the best practices. Do not manipulate the DOM directly. Why would you want the onchange event to be triggered when you are setting the model value.  Set your model value from the component class and everything else should fall in place.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this,

```
document.getElementById("itemText").value = response.items[0].item;
```

instead try assigning the value directly to the binding property (should be done at the component level inorder to have access to the `inputValue`),

```
 this.inputValue = response.items[0].item;
```

and use the 2-way binding syntax as well.